# prepare_cached dbi inside a recursion

Tags: perl, dbi

II am using the DBi to call a table on the DB recurisvly when i use the prepare function every thing works fine but when i use the prepare_cached instead i get an error message that prepare_cached failed

below a snippet of my code

```
sub rec {

my $data = shift;
my $dbh = shift;

if($x eq 'foo') { 

return 1;
 }

my $query="select x from table where z =?";

my $sth=$dbh->prepare_cached($query);
$sth= $dbh->execute($data);

 while(my ($x)=$sth->fetchrow_array) {   
$rec($x,$dbh);

}

}
```

Could someone help what could be the problem ?

Comment: This won't work with `use strict;` because you use `$x` way before you define it. And why don't you prepare your query outside of the sub? You could just pass the statement handle around instead of the whole dbh.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are iterating over $sth and while doing this, recursing and executing again. since this acts on the same $sth this can't work (prepare_cached will call $sth->finish, see DBI docs).

So if possible, fetch your rows into an array, do $sth->finish and then recurse over the array. Or use a normal prepare(). depending on the DBS this might be performant enough.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in this case you should be using the "$if_active" parameter for prepare_cached, probably setting it to 3, like so: 
       $sth = $dbh->prepare_cached($query, {}, 3)
What this will do, however, is that if you're recursing faster than your queries complete, as is likely, any performance gain you might get from using prepare_cached will be lost: if the statement handle in the cache is still in use, it will create a new one for you.

tinita's advice sounds good, but I would point out that there's not usually any reason to call $sth->finish yourself (it's essentially mis-named, really it means "I am finished with this, so throw away the rest of the data in this set stashed on the server").